# How to get large amounts of data into a docker image?

Tags: docker

I want to upload a significant amount of images for processing to use in a Docker instance.

As I have observed this is normally done by a download script (where the images are downloaded to the instance).

I have several terabytes of images so I do not want to download them each time.  Is there a way to get my images to a specific location in the Docker instance?

What is the standard way of doing this?

Comment: If I understand you, you want to be able to update the container without having to redownload the images, correct?  What you could do is to have a directory on the host with all of the images and then add it to the container as a volume.  Then, in the container, you can check to see if that directory exists or not.

Comment: Do you really want to add data to the docker image or only to the docker container ("instance" of docker image)? You are mixing container/image in your question, so it isn't clear.

Comment: @JanGaraj thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: You would typically use bind mounts for something like this to expose files on your host inside the container. https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/